# Current Ramp with constant voltage.

Tags: circuit-design

I am trying to figure out a way to make a ramp (0A - Amax) with a constant voltage. Basically I have a SPST switch that is connected to a 24VDC battery. I need a ramped current output from 0A to 1.9A. Preferably a roughly linear ramp with a 2 sec ramp time. (I'm not sure about that 2 sec so how to get to that would be helpful) I don't even know if this is possible. Any help or direction would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What load is the current going into?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, Ohms law says that if the voltage is constant and the current is changing, then the resistance must be inversely change. If you have a constant resistance load and want a current ramp through it, the voltage needs to ramp.

Comment: You cannot have a fixed voltage and zero amps flowing. As mentioned above the voltage MUST rise from zero to whatever voltage gives you the amps you want. Have you read Ohms Law?

Comment: @GeorgeWhite Well, s/he's technically describing an inductor.

Comment: Yes, I am wanting to send a varying current signal through a solenoid. I assumed the voltage had to be constant. But perhaps it does not.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you´ll ever get a constant voltage applied in a load with linear behavior current flowing through, since $$V(t)=R\times I(t)$$ If current is a linear function: $$ I(t) = kt + b$$ then the voltage is going to have the same behavior.

A simple example you can build to apply a varying voltage to yield a ramping current is creating a current source applied to a capacitor and such source driven by a PNP transistor. Then applying the signal to a buffer and finally to the load.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffY6Zg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

That´s a simple schematic showing how you could somehow design your circuit.
Calculate R and C in order to yield any desired ramp by using $$I=C\frac{dv}{dt}$$ and assuming the voltage across R3 is going to be constant up to a limit, which is when the voltage across the capacitor causes the Base-Collector junction to be reverse-biased, thus not behaving like a constant current source anymore.

Comment: That is a good point, V=IR. If the voltage is constant and the current changes then so must the resistance. I am trying to mimic the signal sent from a piece of construction equipment to a solenoid valve (An inductor). If the stats of solenoid don't change then the resistance cannot change and therefore the voltage would have to change, correct?